# Angular 2 How to sort multiple object using dropdown box?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I would like sort Json object based on drop-down selection

```html
 <select class="form-control form-control" name="">
    <option value="">Sort By</option>
    <option value="">Name</option>
     <option value="">Date</option>
 </select>
```

JSON object

```html
 "users": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "date": "2017-05-26 00:00:00.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Kevin",
        "date": "2017-05-27 00:00:00.0"
    },
 ]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would try binding those `<option></option>` to `(click)` events that triggered sorts on the `users` array. So in you HTML you could do this...

```
 <select class="form-control form-control" name="">
    <option value="">Sort By</option>
    <option (click)="sort('name') value="">Name</option>
     <option (click)="sort('date')" value="">Date</option>
 </select>
```

And for your code...

```
public users: any[] = [{
    "name": "John",
    "date": "2017-05-26 00:00:00.0"
}, {
    "name": "Kevin",
    "date": "2017-05-27 00:00:00.0"
}];

public sort(by: string): void {
    if (by === 'name') {
        this.users.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            return a.name.toUpperCase() - b.name.toUpperCase();
        });
    } else if (by === 'date') {
        this.users.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
        });
    }
}
```

This is obviously a fast and dirty method, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It is better to use the (change) event binding on the select tag. Otherwise if you change the selection using arrow keys, programatically or through other means, the click event won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

First use [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) on your select tag to bind its selection to a variable in your component (In this case the variable 'selected') as well as binding the change event to a sort function (In this case the function 'sort()'):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="sort()" class="form-control form-control">
    <option value="">Sort By</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
     <option value="date">Date</option>
 </select>
```

Secondly, create a function in your component to apply the sort. Depending on how you want to sort, the sorting function may be different than the one written below as this is only an example. In which case you'd use the conditional 'if/else' or 'switch' or other logic to apply the sort depending on which option is selected.

```
sort() {
    this.users.sort(function(a,b)
    {
        return (a[this.selected] < b[this.selected]) ? 1 : ((b[this.selected] < a[this.selected]) ? -1 : 0);
    });
}
```

See [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-syntax) for more info on data binding in angular.